# NiFi: get all elements of the same tag in XML using EvaluateXpath processor

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, apache-nifi, hortonworks-dataflow

Trying to parse the xml below in NiFi and would like to parse all the ids out and make multiple web service calls for each id.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Header>   
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <store-Ids>
            <Id>69E32281-0484</Id>
            <Id>3002AFCD-B494</Id>
            <Id>2C9E17AC-9D97</Id>
            <Id>98E8EB10-7D6A</Id>
            <Id>F8D5F93C-1455</Id>
            <Id>98655C3F-B58C</Id>
            <Id>8AE4FD0A-6000</Id>
            <Id>E56FE4CA-0D83</Id>
         </store-Ids>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Is there a way to parse out all the id inside Id tags? Either as an array ( 69E32281-0484, 3002AFCD-B494.............) or as a string (69E32281-0484                3002AFCD-B4942C9E17AC-9D97...............) using the Evaluate-XPath or Evaluate-xQuery Processors?

```
//*[local-name()='Id']/text() -------- This gives me only the 1st id. and 
//*[local-name()='Id'][2]/text() ------- This gives the 2nd id and so on....
//Id -------------------------------- This returns "Empty string set"
```

As the number of Ids are going to be dynamic. It is not possible to hard code the counter value like [0], [1], [2]........ to get the value of each id.

PS: There are many other ways to get this done in NiFi. But would like to know if there is a way to read XML with EvaluateXpath processor and get all the id tag values as an array or as a text.

Related links

1) https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/101922/how-to-use-evaluatexpath-to-get-xml-roots-attribut.html

2)https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/140605/evaluatexpath-cant-return-multiple-node-values.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently EvaluateXPath only allows a single element in the Nodeset, even when the destination is flowfile-content. I have written up an improvement Jira ([NIFI-5187](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5187)) to cover the support for Nodesets with multiple elements.

As a workaround, you can use EvaluateXQuery with `//*/Id` and it will issue a flow file for each of your IDs. Then you can process each individually, calling whichever web services you like.